# Importing packages from parent folder

Tags: java, import, directory

I'm trying to import a file (DrawingPanel for those interested) from one directory (let's call it "Projects") into several Java files in different subdirectories. Is this a possibility without copying the file into each subdirectory individually?

Comment: Use an IDE (Eclipse/IntelliJ or other) and it will do the job for you to add correct import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to copy any files. Just need to specify a correct import.
For example, your project structure is:

```
com   
   |_projects
            |_DrawingPanel.java
            |_subdir1
                    |_Panel1.java
                    |_Panel2.java
```

As you can see, `DrawingPanel` is located in the parent package.
To import it to the `Panel1` and `Panel2` classes you need to add `import com.projects.DrawingPanel;` to them:

`Panel1.java`

```
package com.projects.subdir1;

import com.projects.DrawingPanel;

public class Panel1 {
}
```

`Panel2.java`

```
package com.projects.subdir2;

import com.projects.DrawingPanel;

public class Panel2 {
}
```

You can read more about packages and imports [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html).

Comment: Oh! That makes a lot more sense. Thanks so much!

Comment: How far do I need to go with the directory reference ("com.projects.subdir1")? It is telling me that the package DNE.

Comment: In a package you need to specify a directory where this Java file is located. For example, `Panel1.java` is located in `com/projects/subdir1` directory, that is why its package will be `com.projects.subdir1`.

Comment: Do I also need to add the package statement to the top of the DrawingPanel?

Comment: Every Java class must contain a package statement which indicates the directory in which it is located, so yes - you need to add it to the each your Java class.

Comment: Awesome. So just to recap: A package in Java is similar to a 'folder' in the windows library? It group the files together so they can share classes/methods/etc with each other.

Comment: Yes, you can read about it more [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-packages) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packages-in-java/).