# Importing package from parent directory

Tags: java, import, directory, package

I want to import a custom package `ArrGen` to a java file `file.java`. `file.java` is in a subdirectory.

```
Java
   |_ArrGen (package)
           |_IntArr.java
   |_DSA
        |_Step1
        |_Step2
        |_Step3
              |_Arrays
                      |_file.java
```

I tried doing this in `file.java` (from an answer to a question similar to this question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58644914/importing-packages-from-parent-folder))):

```
package Java.DSA.Step3;
import Java.ArrGen.*;

public class largestElement{ // largestElement == file.java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }
}
```

But the `package` line gave this error:
`The declared package "Java.DSA.Step3" does not match the expected package "" Java(536871240)`

And the `import` line gave this error:
`The import Java cannot be resolved Java(268435846)`

I'm using VS Code.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with your arrangement apart from bad [naming](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions) so it might be something to do with your IDE. I don't use IDEs and have *never* used VS Code but presumably it can import Maven projects. If so, you can import [this](https://technojeeves.com/tech/maven-proj.zip) which uses your exact structure and will run. I don't think a package named `java` is allowed, so I renamed that `jaava`. Change the names as you wish, but package names are lower case.

Comment: @g00se I'm learning DSA through Java and I don't think that I'll be using Maven to learn DSA. So, can you please assist me to do this without Maven?

Answer (score 0):

Your package path is wrong. Therefore you should change `package Java.DSA.Step3;` to `package Java.DSA.Step3.Arrays;`. I think it'll help!

Comment: Didn't work. This error is shown:  `The declared package "Java.DSA.Step3.Arrays" does not match the expected package ""Java(536871240)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69872033/the-declared-package-package-name-does-not-match-the-expected-package-in-vs. A similar problem has been solved in this post, might it'll help you!